# How to fix full outer join of two tables when not all values exist in both tables

Tags: sql, presto

I have two tables I want to join. One of the variables I'm joining is the country name. However, one of the tables has values, while the other table doesn't have all the values. This produces blank rows without all the data.

This is what I've currently trying

```
select 'display' as channel, date, market, revenue, spend
from (
  select trim(market) as market, date, revenue
  from table_a
) ABC
FULL JOIN (
  select 
    case geosegmentation_countries
      when 'united kingdom' then 'UK'
      when 'germany' then 'DE'
      when 'france' then 'FR'
      when 'italy' then 'IT'
      when 'spain' then 'ES'
      else 'Other'
    end as market, 
    date, 
    spend
  from table_b
) OM on ABC.market = OM.market and ABC.date = OM.Date
```

The `ABC` table doesn't have the "other" value in markets. This is giving me this output, with blank dates and markets.
[image: This is giving me this output, with blank dates and markets]

How can I fix this join so that the other market data has the correct dates coming through, with the 'other' data being filled in the `market` column?

Comment: We need both sample table data and the matching expected result. (As formatted text, not images.)

Comment: No table is called `DBM` in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are joining on `market` and returning it.  I'm not sure why you are using a `full join` (your explanation suggests a `left join`, but it is not clear what table has all the rows you want).

That said, to get `'Other'`, use [`COALESCE()`](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/conditional.html#coalesce) in the outer `SELECT`:

```
select 'display' as channel, date,
       coalesce(market, 'other') as market,
       revenue, spend
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I completely agree, a left join would have been better. I finally understand the coalesce function now!